# The jquery.ajax option - data property type

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

In jQuery.ajax( [settings ] ), one option is data.
According to the official document,
data ,Type: Object, String.

But in chrome or firefox, I tried below code,note:contentType is 'application/json',

```
var json={data:100};

    var options = {
        type: 'post',
        url: "test2.html",
        data: json,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (result) {

        }
$.ajax(options);
```

[image: the screenshot in firebug]

Edit the code, change the data as data:JSON.stringify(json):

```
var json={data:100};      
var options = {
    type: 'post',
    url: "test2.html",
    data: JSON.stringify(json), 
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (result) {

    }
```

$.ajax(options);

[image]

What's the difference between these two types as data?
And how will they affect the server variable like post variable and get variable ?

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` is used to pass data to server in the form of strings.

Comment: yes, I know that.As the type of data is Object or String.This means we can send both json object and string.